# Problem with controller return statement not performed (about redirect)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a side project and it's been delayed for several days. When I run my code, I always can't run it from the "return redirect:/" part of the controller.

The result I expected is that I think of moving from sentence "return redirect:/" to another page, but everything seems fine inside, but only sentence "return redirect:/" is not performed.

I am using Mysql, SpringBoot, JPA, Spring Data Jpa, Lombok. What is the problem?

**This is View to receive email and password.**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href ="/css/sample.css">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/font.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/navbar.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    
    <title>loginpage</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function functionclick() {
        let email =  document.getElementById('exampleDropdownFormEmail1').value;
        let password = document.getElementById('exampleDropdownFormPassword1').value;

        if (email == "" || password == "") {
          alert("회원 정보를 입력하세요");
          history.back();
        } else{
          const url = new URL("/trylogin",location);
          url.searchParams.append('email',email);
          url.searchParams.append('password',password);
          location = url;

        }
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example">

    <!-- Example Code -->
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <form class="px-4 py-3" method="get" action="login">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" class="form-label">이메일을 입력하세요</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" placeholder="email@example.com" name = "email">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" class="form-label">비밀번호를 입력하세요.</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" placeholder="Password" name = "password">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">
              비밀번호 기억하기
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ONCLICK="functionclick()">확인</button>
      </form>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://localhost:8080/signup">회원가입 하기</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://localhost:8080/forgotpassword">비밀번호 찾기</a>
    </div>
    
    <!-- End Example Code -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**This is LoginController**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {


    @Autowired
    private
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/trylogin")
    public String login(LoginDto loginDto) {
        try {
            if(userService.login(loginDto).isPresent()) {
                return "redirect:/loginSuccess";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "redirect:/loginFailed";
        }
        return "redirect:/loginFailed";
    }

    @GetMapping("/loginSuccess")
    public String loginSuccess() {
        return "login_success";
    }

    @GetMapping("/loginFailed")
    public String loginFailed()  {
        return "login_failed";
    }
}
```

**It is a service layer and the Repository used spring data jpa.**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Optional<Users> login(LoginDto loginDto) throws Exception{
        return usersRepository.findByEmailAndPassword(loginDto.getEmail(), loginDto.getPassword());
    }
}
```

**This is the Users entity to perform the query.**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"ssn","phone_number"})})
public class Users {

    @Column(name = "email", length = 40, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @Id
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 25, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", length = 12, nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name =  "ssn", length = 13, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String ssn;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    @Column(name = "point")
    private Long point;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "postedUser")
    private List<PostInfo> uploadedPost = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId")
    private List<PointHistory> pointHistories = new ArrayList<>();

    @Embedded
    private Dates dates;

    public Users(UserInfoDto userInfoDto){
        this.setEmail(userInfoDto.getEmail());
        this.setPassword(userInfoDto.getPassword());
        this.setPhoneNumber(userInfoDto.getPhone_number());
        this.setSsn(userInfoDto.getSsn());
        this.setPoint(0L);
        this.setName(userInfoDto.getName());

        Address address = new Address(
                userInfoDto.getCity_name(),
                userInfoDto.getTown_name(),
                userInfoDto.getStreet_name(),
                userInfoDto.getZip_code(),
                userInfoDto.getDetails()
        );

        this.setAddress(address);

        List<PostInfo> postInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<PointHistory> pointHistoryList = new ArrayList<>();

        this.setUploadedPost(postInfoList);
        this.setPointHistories(pointHistoryList);

        Dates dates = new Dates(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now());

        this.setDates(dates);
    }

    public void setEmail(String id) {
        this.email = id;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setSsn(String ssn) {
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setPoint(Long point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public void setUploadedPost(List<PostInfo> uploadedPost) {
        this.uploadedPost = uploadedPost;
    }

    public void setPointHistories(List<PointHistory> pointHistories) {
        this.pointHistories = pointHistories;
    }

    public void setDates(Dates dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
    }
}
```

**This is LoginDto (To transfer to the controller)**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LoginDto {
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

**The page for redirection.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login Success</title>

  <script type = "text/javascript">
    alert("로그인 성공");
    location.href = "/";
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, Can you please describe how you load the view pages (name of Template Engine if using any), also mention the location & name of view files (name of HTML view pages).

Comment: Sure! I only used thymeleaf and file's(view) path is src/main/resources/templates and The html page name to use this logic is the loginpage.html!